# QPalette and app.setStyleSheet() not impacting child Widget colors

Tags: css, pyqt5, qpalette

I've got a pretty large PyQt5 application that I'm finally polishing with some colors.  I've created a `QPalette()` and pass that to the app at launch. For the most part, it works (yay!). But not all of the child widgets are picking up the QPalette settings, and so I added a StyleSheet, but that again isn't working consistently. The only way I've been able to impact a widget color is by directly adding it when the widget is created, which is fine in something small.

The Main window:

```
    class MyBigApplication(QMainWindow, QWidget):
            def __init__(self):
                super(MyBigApplication, self).__init__()
        
            # ... load the various pieces, which include prompting user login and making some background connections.
        
            # Build the GUI
            def init_ui(self):
        
                self.statusBar().showMessage('Welcome to MyBigApplication!')
        
                self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        
                # Initialize tab screen
                self.tabs = QTabWidget()
                self.tabs.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Triangular)
                self.foo = fooTab(self, self.tabs)
                self.bar = barTab(self, self.tabs)
                self.baz = bazTab(self, self.tabs)
        
                self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.tabs,0,1,4,1)
                
                main_widget = QWidget()
                main_widget.setLayout(self.grid_layout)
                self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        
                # Additional setup of menus and such
        
        if __name__.endswith('__main__'):
            app = QCoreApplication.instance()
            while app is not None:
                app.close()
            app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        
            app.setStyle('Fusion')
        
            dark_palette = QPalette()
        
            # Define some colors to get started
            light_grey = QColor(243,243,243)
            medium_grey = QColor(211,216,219)
            dark_grey = QColor(52,59,64)
        
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(dark_grey)) 
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(medium_grey))
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(dark_grey))
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor(25, 25, 25)) # almost black
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.Link, QColor(green)) 
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(half_green))
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, QColor(light_grey))
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipBase, QColor(light_grey))
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipText, QColor(light_grey))
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, QColor(light_grey))
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, QColor(light_grey))
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.BrightText, Qt.red)
            dark_palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.black)
        
            app.setPalette(dark_palette)
            
            app.setFont(QFont('Franklin Gothic Book', 9))
        
            app.setStyleSheet("""
                QMainWindow {
        
                }
                QToolTip { 
                    color: #f3f3f3; 
                    background-color: #2a82da; 
                    border: 1px solid white; 
                }
                QTableView {   # This works
                    border: 1px solid #218a21 
                }
                QPushButton {   # And this works
                    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px,
                }
                QPushButton:hover {   # But this does not
                    background-color: red,
                }
                QTableView::item:alternate {  # And this also does not
                    background-color: #d3d8db,
                }
                """)
        
            execute = MyBigApplication()
            sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The fooTab includes tables of data:

```
class fooTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, tabs):
        super(fooTab,self).__init__()
        self.root = parent
        self.tabs = tabs

    def init_foo_one(self):
        self.foo_tab = QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.foo_tab, 'FOO')
        tab_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        foo_id_box = QGroupBox('FOO DATA')

        clear_button = QPushButton('Clear Foo Data Table')
        clear_button.clicked.connect(self.clear_foo_table)
        
        # Set up the Table Model/View/Proxy
        self.foo_id_table = QTableView()

        self.foo_data_model = fooTableModel()  # This is a QAbstractTableModel class
        
        self.foo_data_model.setDataDict(data)
        self.foo_id_table_columns = ['1','2','3','4']
        self.foo_resizable_cols = [0,1,2,3,4]
        self.foo_data_model.setDataHeader(self.foo_id_table_columns)
        self.foo_table_proxy.setSourceModel(self.foo_data_model)
        self.foo_id_table.setModel(self.foo_table_proxy)
        self.foo_id_table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.foo_id_table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.foo_id_table.setWordWrap(False)
        self.foo_id_table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        
        # Create a layout for that box using a grid
        foo_id_box_layout = QGridLayout()

        # Add the widgets into the layout
        foo_id_box_layout.addWidget(self.foo_id_table,0,0,1,5)
        foo_id_box_layout.addWidget(clear_button,1,2,1,1)
        
        # Setup the layout to be displayed in the box
        foo_id_box.setLayout(foo_id_box_layout)
        tab_layout.addWidget(foo_id_box)
        self.foo_tab.setLayout(tab_layout)
```

The bazTab:

```
    class BazTab(QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent, tabs):
            super(BazTab,self).__init__()
            self.root = parent
            self.tabs = tabs
            self.h1_font = QFont()
            self.h1_font.setBold(True)
            self.h1_font.setPointSize(16)
            self.h2_font = QFont()
            self.h2_font.setBold(False)
            self.h2_font.setPointSize(12)
            self.h3_font = QFont()
            self.h3_font.setBold(True)
            self.init_ui()
    
    
        def init_ui(self):
            self.component_tab = QScrollArea()
            self.tabs.addTab(self.baz_tab, 'Baz')
            self.tab_layout = QHBoxLayout()
            self.component_tab.setLayout(self.tab_layout)
            
            component_button_box = QGroupBox('Various Buttons')
            component_button_layout = QVBoxLayout()
            component_button_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
            component_button_box.setLayout(component_button_layout)
            self.tab_layout.addWidget(component_button_box)
    
            first_button = QPushButton('Request #1')
            first_button.clicked.connect(self.request_one)
            component_button_layout.addWidget(first_button)
            
            second_button = QPushButton('Request #2')
            second_button.clicked.connect(self.request_two)
            component_button_layout.addWidget(second_button)
            
            # Several more buttons created in here
            # None of these buttons look like the buttons in the info dialog (which have a color from the QPalette)
```

I can manually edit the `QTableView` to show alternating colors, only if I add it to each instance.
I cannot get some of the QPushButtons to change, even when I add each instance's styleSheet.

Using the QPalette has saved a ton, by not having to modify widget by widget.  For the extra details, I'm fine to use the `app.setStyleSheet` except that it doesn't always work.

Is it me, or is this just the way it is?

Comment: As the documentation of [`setPalette()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setPalette) clearly notes: "**Warning:** Do not use this function in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets. When using style sheets, the palette of a widget can be customized using the "color", "background-color", "selection-color", "selection-background-color" and "alternate-background-color"."

Comment: Also: the stylesheet has multiple typos (the commas instead of semicolon), and you should use the [`alternate-background-color`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#alternate-background-color-prop).

Comment: @musicamante  Oh, those stupid, stupid semicolons!  Putting those into place in the StyleSheet portion of the main application made everything work, and I was able to take off the component-specific stylesheet edits.

Regarding the warning to not combine `setPalette()` with `setStyleSheet()` - I guess the solution is to ditch the palette altogether? There's things I need to be able to do, like improving the hover action on a button, that I don't see available in palette, or that have unintended side-effects because the palette control touches more components than I want to modify.

Comment: You have to consider that the palette is a *hint*, the Qt style (without style sheets) decides how to use those colors or even ignore them, for instance some styles use the `Button` role as color for certain elements of some widgets, while others use the `Window` role, and some even *blend* different color roles; the QStyle also decides if and how to use the palette for states (like `:hover`). Also remember that, when using style sheets, some color properties alter the widget palette (see [this related answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/71231822)).

Comment: Note that the quote in my first comment can be misleading. In reality, you *can* use `setPalette()` and stylesheets, as long as you do it with awareness: remember that style sheet color values can also use a [palette role](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#paletterole), meaning that you can set the **application** palette with custom colors, and set color values in the stylesheet corresponding to any role you need. Note that this will **not** work with `widget.setPalette()`, as the style sheet of the widget can only access the palette of the application.